# How to consume a .net web service from a remote server with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

How to build a .net web service to communicate with a remote server (different domain) using javascript. It's better soap or rest? What HEADERS must be defined so that my server accect to recover the data. Like this web service that I believe made the already well https://api.github.com/users/peterbe/gists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found! I did a Web service with web api and:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors//In Nu get
config.EnableCors();//In WebApiConfig Register
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]//Above of Controller class
```

It's work

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure:
You want to build a webservice with .net and build a client JavaScript, right.

For building a webservice in .net have look at a framework. IMHO these helps a lot.

[ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [Servicestack](https://servicestack.net/) to start with.

For client, search for: "javascript consuming web service"
you will find a lot of samples.

Comment: soap and rest: there is no better. it depends on what you want to do. no decision is necessary. you can use both.

Comment: I know web api. if i can use it, is ok. But because is a remote sever, i thinks i must add info like the headers, but i know what

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "remote server"?

Comment: I am no english speaker. I use google translate ;-) i would like say. my web service is on mysite.com and i want consumate it with mysite2.com. No on same hosting.

Comment: It's work i did "Set the Allowed Origins" with web api